# Javascript to hide upload and actions but keep new

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please provide some JavaScript code so I can display New but hide Upload and Actions in the menu of a document library.

Comment: Is it SharePoint 2013?

Comment: What have you tried yourself sofar? StackOverflow is not a place where others do your job.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to hide some ribbon buttons, you can use a Content Editor web part in the library page, add some css to hide those button. 
some thing like this:

```html
<style>
#Ribbon\.ListItem\.New\.NewFolder-Large
{
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

A more decent way is to deploy a SharePoint feature (Element.xml) to hide certain buttons. http://www.ktskumar.com/blog/2010/10/hide-button-from-sharepoint-ribbon/